# Is it possible to get the raw build log from a TeamCity build?

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to get the raw build log from a TeamCity build?  I've written a custom test runner that gets run as a commandline build step and reports test results back by printing `##teamcity...` lines to stdout.  The build log from TeamCity seems to be stripping these out when it recognises them.  I'd like to see the raw output to help debug my test runner.

**Update:**
Apparently this simply isn't possible.  neverov (I assume Dimitry Neverov of JetBrains?) has explained this and given a workaround so I've accepted his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download it by clicking "Download full build log" on build log page.

Comment: That doesn't work for me using TeamCity 6.5.5 (build 18087).  It seems to give the the same text as the build log on the website.  It definitely isn't giving me the `##teamcity` lines.

Comment: It turns out that not all service messages are equal, and TeamCity hides some of them even in the full build log. Test results messages are also hidden. So the only way to debug it is to run build script locally or on agent. If there are messages in output, but TeamCity ignore them, please post a bug.

Comment: Just in case, as of 2021, for debugging purposes you may try using configuration parameter `teamcity.internal.build.serviceMessages.logOriginal=true`

Answer (score 13):

You can see the raw output from the build agent by looking in the agents `/logs` directory. This shows the unparsed data that is being hidden on the build output shown in the TeamCity console.

For example `c:\TeamCity-Agent\logs\teamcity-build.log`.

Answer (score 2):

I see that this question was asked long time ago (almost 10 years ago) but nothing changed in TeamCity.

I faced similar issue with test reporter and found a way to get raw log without connecting to build agent and getting it from there (it may be difficult). My solution does not cover the whole build log, but can be helpful when step is run via custom script in Build Steps.

So the solution is to add `| tee e2e_raw.log` into required build step script. For example we run tests in Docker by running docker-compose command:
[image]

`tee` will duplicate all the output into the file. Original output will be the same and will be parsed by TeamCity as usual.

You should also add a line into artifacts field to make build able to collect newly created artifact (Build General settings):
[image]

After that you will see a new archive in artifacts tab with raw log for this build step:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite tell if this is what you were talking about when you refer to `##teamcity...` lines in your question, but this is what I'm currently doing for command-line build steps (which is currently all I do):

```sh
##teamcity[testStarted name='dummyTestName' captureStandardOutput='true']

echo "Do your command-line build steps here."

##teamcity[testFinished name='dummyTestName']
```

It's sort of a hacky workaround, but it will result in stdout/stderr being displayed on the build log page in the TeamCity web UI.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers here before me. I would add that your TeamCity master holds log files for the builds, and you can get them on the command line.

Have a look in `<TeamCity Data Directory>/system/artifacts/<project ID>/<build configuration name>/<internal_build_id>/.teamcity/logs`.

This mattered to me because

1. The logs on the TeamCity agents were getting removed after a day or so, but the logs on the master were still available.
2. I wanted to grep them on the machine itself without having to download multiple, sizeable log files or use my web browser to make multiple page views.

Answer (score -1):

There's an option on the build log to see 'detailed / verbose' - it shows all the service messages. I've seen it since TC9.